# Child exploitation

Tags: sunnah, parents, children

Assalamu alaikum brother, my question is that Islam orders the child to obey his parents even if they ask him to leave his wife and give away his wealth as charity. But my question is if the father really exploits the child very much and the child is suffering of many mental damages because of him . Will Allah reward the child for his patience

Comment: Where have you got these claims (about the child obedience) from?

Answer (score 1):

Obedience always has its limitations.

If a father has vices like drinking, gambling and womanising, should the child give up his wealth to him?

If you were that child with an immoral father, should you disobey him only for the RIGHT REASONS? Your refusal only saves him from ruins.

If your father ever asks you to buy him a crate of alcohols, would you really? If you disobey, will you feel guilty?

If your father wants your wealth and uses that to gamble on the horses, buy gifts for many girlfriends, drink boozes and smoke weeds, would you obey him and let him abuse your wealth like that?

If your drunkard father ever asks you for a ladder and that he wants to climb unto a roof of a highest building, would you really give him the ladder and let him fall to his death? Your disobedience will only save his life. (I once did that to my father. I took a ladder away from him and he cussed at me. Better that than see him dead).

If you give him all your wealth, then there will be nothing left, none to pay for the future care of your parents in old age, nothing for your starving wife in her old age, nothing for your homeless children.